# Accordian collapse menu side icon change when expand

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is menu with collapse menu. I want to make it right side icon change when expand menu.

i want to add `<i class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right"></i>` in this code `fa-caret-down` icon when click `fa-caret-up`

```css
.category-list {
  width="100px";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3">  
<div class="category-list" id="category-list">
  <div class="list-name" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#all">All
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right"></i>
  </div>

  <ul id="all" class="collapse">
    <li><a href="">Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<div class="list-name" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nxt">Next
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right"></i>
  </div>

  <ul id="nxt" class="collapse">
    <li><a href="">Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>



</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the `.fa-caret-up` element and place the appropriate css rules to show or hide the carets based on `.list-name` element's `aria-expanded` attribute's state:

1. When *aria-expanded="**true**"* : Only the `.fa-caret-up` icon will be visible
2. When *aria-expanded="**false**"* : Only the `.fa-caret-down` icon will be visible

```css
.category-list {
  width="100px";
}

.list-name:not([aria-expanded="true"]) .fa.fa-caret-up,
.list-name[aria-expanded="false"] .fa.fa-caret-up,
.list-name[aria-expanded="true"] .fa.fa-caret-down {
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3">  
<div class="category-list" id="category-list">
  <div class="list-name" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#all">All
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-up pull-right"></i>
  </div>

  <ul id="all" class="collapse">
    <li><a href="">Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test8</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you want the icons to fade out smoothly, you have to do it with javascript. CSS transition does not animate display property. Also, in my opinion, if you fade out one caret you have to wait until it finishes it's animation in order to fade in the other caret, resulting in a non user-friendly UI

Comment: I want another thing.. i need to make it looks like Accordion menu.. only one menu item can enable and other collapse..